# System.IO StreamWriter Class Differs Between a Windows Application and a Class Libarary Application

Tags: c#, dll, streamwriter

I am creating a class library by converting code from a .NET Framework 4.6.2 Windows Application which I downloaded from CodeProject.  The class library (DLL) has target framework of .NETStandard 1.6.

I have run into a problem with the System.IO StreamWriter class not being consistent between the two applications. The image below shows red-line errors for fileName and outputFile.Close() in the DLL project.  The same errors do not occur in the Windows app.:

[fileName is of type String and outputFile is of type StreamWriter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ihcxd.png)

After using Visual Studio's "Go To Definiton" option, I found that the StreamWriter version in the System.IO for the Windows app, has both 1) a constructor that takes a string argument, and 2) a Close() method.  Both of those features are missing in the StreamWriter version for the DLL.

So my question is "Can I somehow "fix" my DLL project properties so that it can use the C# code without change, or do I have to modify the code?".

Comment: I disagree that this question is an exact duplicate of an existing question.  My question is about fixing properties or fixing code.  After doing more research and testing, I have found that I probably chose the wrong target framework for my DLL application.  Had I chosen, let's say, .NET Framework 4.6.2 instead of .NETStandard 1.6, the ported code would have worked.  The post called "Vnext Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.IO.Stream' " is about "things are missing from the framework".  I probably just chose the wrong framework altogether.  More testing will tell.

Comment: So, indeed, the problem was the framework chosen for my class library project. By changing it to .NET Framework 4.6.2, I was able to port code from the Windows Application without modification.  I still disagree that this post is a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify your code. `System.IO.StreamWriter.ctor(string)` and `System.IO.StreamWriter.Close()` aren't part of the .NET Standard 1.6 APIs.

Comment: Or choose a different framework, I think.

Comment: Changing the framework solved the problem.  See my comment above.